# Sparse File Compression Zones vs Sparse Ranges

Tags: c#, sparse-file

I am new to sparse files and wondering if compression zones and sparse ranges are the same thing.

I recently learned the term compression units from here:
http://www.flexhex.com/docs/articles/sparse-files.phtml

> When it comes to a compressed or a sparse file, NTFS divides the file into chunks called compression units.

However in this example they have sparse ranges:
https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/CSSparseFile-6e26dc97

> SetSparseRange...The minimum sparse size is 64KB.

From reading elsewhere I see that NTFS disk clusters are 4kb in size and windows defines a compression unit as a collection of 16 units each 4kb...
16 * 4 == 64kb so are they the same?

I can how in Microsoft NT world they have a different term (compression units) than others (sparse ranges) but I'm not sure if I have this correct.

I am having a tough time finding thorough documentation so if you know of any resources I will gladly look into them.

TIA

Comment: why is this question tagged c#?

Comment: because I am working with sparse files in the c# language

Comment: yes, but the question is nothing to do with c#, unless you have problems with c# code then use that tag.  It's more to do with ntfs than c#, where's that tag?  (BTW: that's where experts you need will more likely to be at.)